# Highcharts - How do I dynamically change Marker radius when zooming?

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highcharts with series type of "scatter". I also have the x-axis zoom functionality enabled.

Now it would be nice to adapt the Marker radius to the zoom level.
Something like:

```
events: {
    selection: function(event) {
        var extremesObject = event.xAxis[0],
            min = extremesObject.min,
            max = extremesObject.max;

        this.series[0].marker.radius = (max - min)/5;
    }
```

}

The last line `this.series[0]...` is the code I'm looking for.

I tried this:

```
        jQuery.each(this.series[1].data, function (i, point) {
            point.update({
                marker: {
                    radius: 10 / (max - min)
                }
            });
        });
```

But this gives me an error when used on redraw event. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/dbX4F/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in the current version of highcharts as it doesn't have an API to update the series options. However, it is possible in the v3Beta release.

The maths of the zooming needs some work, but I've got the basics working here: http://jsfiddle.net/Jrh2G/

```
events: {
    selection: function (event) {
        var extremesObject = event.xAxis[0],
         min = extremesObject.min,
         max = extremesObject.max;
        console.log(min + " " + max);
        // The maths needs some work to make the radius scale better with min/max.
        // Also, you should probabl take into account min/max y values as well.
        this.series[0].update({marker:{radius:10/(max-min)}});
}
```

Comment: Great, this works! But I'm not sure if I should use the Beta version because this is for a commercial server...

I tried something like this using non-beta, but gives me an error: `jQuery.each(this.series[0].data, function(i, point) { point.update({marker:{radius:10/(max-min)}}); });`

Comment: The beta release is due out this month. I've been looking at it or our production environment as we need the bubblecharts feature. It's looking pretty good so far, although I reported one bug in the bubblecharts.

Comment: I had to put this in the redraw event callback, because I have a master-detail configuration  (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail). The error I get says: `Error: TypeError: j.redraw is not a function
Source File: http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js
Line: 190`

Comment: Perhaps you can post a simplified example to jsfiddle ?

Comment: You need to call update(option,false) on each point. The false tells highcharts not to redraw. If you then return true in the redraw function, it redraws at the end. http://jsfiddle.net/VhqaQ/.

Comment: It does if you select in the upper area of the chart. I think you need another mechanism to cope with selecting in the master chart.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution. It's possible to pass Point configuration in the same array as the graph data:

```
jQuery.each(data, function(i, val) {
    if (i > min && i < max) {
        detailScatter.push({
            marker: {
                radius: 80 / (max - min)
            },
            x: i,
            y: val
        });
    }
});

detailChart.series[1].setData(detailScatter);
```

Works like a charm - See here: http://jsfiddle.net/dbX4F/3/